# How can I create a Install New Module-style "add button"?

Tags: forms

In the Modules page, there is a button that looks like this:

[image]

Is this easy to reproduce? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You create a sub-item in your `hook_menu()`, then set its type to `MENU_LOCAL_ACTION`.

```
  $items['menu/url'] = array(
    // --snip--
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
    // --snip--
  );
```